# Double Data Approbation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, api

I am looking for something that I have no idea what that name is and i haven't found the good keyword to find more information. I hope someone will be able to tell me what I am looking for.

I have a small application connected to a database and a rest API that has its own database.

The goal is to keep both synchronized.

So if i add an item to my API and it succeed, i can add it in my database. But it need to be true both ways.

Exemple 1 (normal):

> 1- Add Object A In Api --- Response OK 
>   2- Add Object A In DB  --- Response OK 
>   3- Success

Exemple 2 (failed in Api):

> 1- Add Object A In Api --- Response failed 
>   2- Skip Db 
>   3- Log error

Exemple 3 (failed in DB, this is what i want more information on):

> 1- Add Object A In Api --- Response OK 
>   2- Add Object A In DB  --- Response failed 
>   3- Remove Object A from Api 
>   4- Log error

I can't find a way to handle this without lots of try/catch and custom error and i believe it's a common pattern with multiple database that do not share the same unit of work / context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for "[distributed transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction)".  You'll benefit from something outside of your application that helps coordinate this.

Since this is tagged C#, I'll say that Microsoft has several technologies that might help with this.  The specifics will depend on the databases and services you're working with.  That REST service might make things tricky though.

Maybe this is enough to get you started.

Comment: Specifically, the DTC (Distributed Transaction Coordinator). This will work nearly "out of the box" with `TransactionScopes` but you are correct that the REST API may complicate things.

Comment: Thanks, i believe it exactly what i was looking for. And yea the api going to be a problem because all action are final. But I might be able to make myself own api rollback. I will read more about this. Thanks

Comment: I found out about the Action Object that give me the possibility to save the opposite action and invoke them later to rollback if needed. That way I can use distributed transactions to combine both the api and sql. Thanks for the help.